# ?ow to write a user defined function in sql to count the number of characters in a given string (back end code of len function)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In C language, we are using the below logic:

```
const char * z = "testing one two three";
int m;
int charcount;

charcount = 0;
for(m=0; z[m]; m++) {
    if(z[m] != ' ') {
        charcount ++;
    }
}
```

How to do it in T-SQL?

Comment: What have you tried? Does a white space counted?

Comment: What results do you want?  Your code does not print or return anything.

Answer (score 2):

Number of chars except `' '` : `len(replace(<column name>, ' ',''))` , e.g.

```
select len(replace('testing one two three', ' ','')) n
```

Answer (score 1):

I dunno why you don't want to use `LEN()` directly, but...

Just a simple sample (logic)

```
DECLARE @Cnt INT = 0; --Same as the variable `int charcount;`

SELECT @Cnt = @Cnt + 1 --Same as `charcount ++`
FROM Master..SPT_VALUES --Simulate the for loop `for(m=0; z[m]; m++)`
WHERE [Type] = 'P'
      AND
      SUBSTRING('testing one two three', Number, 1) <> ''; --Same as `if(z[m] != ' ')`


SELECT @Cnt;
```

The result is: 18.